# javascript validation to check @ at start of user input: not email validation

Tags: javascript

I have to check whether a form field contains '@' at start of user input & is it contains it at all. It works fine for checking if its at start of the string. But when I add checking whether input contains '@' at all or not. It fails. Here is my code

```
  function email_valid(field) 
    { 
      var apos=field.update.value;
          apos=apos.indexOf('@');
            if (apos>0 ||((apos.contains('@')== 'FALSE')))
              { alert('plz enter valid input');
                return false;
              }
            else 
            { return true; }
    }
```

**EDIT**

*This function in this form is checking both if @ is at 1st place & 2ndly is it in the input at all or not.*

```
   function @_valid(field) 
        { 
          var ref=field.update.value;// I needed ref 4 other things
          var apos=ref.indexOf('@');
          if (apos>=0 )
             {
               if (apos==0)
                   {
                    return true;
                   }
                 else { field.t_update3.value=""; 
                        alert('plz enter a valid refernce');
                        return false;
                      }
                     }
                   else { field.t_update3.value=""; 
                         alert('plz enter a valid refernce');
                         return false;
          }         }
```

Comment: @cdhowie, no, its not email validation. I need '@' at start of input.

Comment: `field.update.value`? What is the `update` child?

Comment: @XCeptable: Oops, sorry.  I have still corrected your title though, since this has nothing whatsoever to do with PHP.

Comment: @cdhowie, but I did not added php tag

Comment: @XCeptable: But the title of the question when you first submitted it was "php user input @ validation".  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4371628/revisions).

Comment: @cdhowie - does it refer to PHP though? @XCeptable is using a comparison `apos.contains('@')== 'FALSE')` which smells like PHP to me. If it truly is JavaScript, a comparison of `if(apos.indexOf('@') != -1)` should suffice.

Comment: @scunliffe: There are no `$` prefixes on any variables.  This cannot be PHP.

Comment: @rhino, field is a reference to form

Comment: @cdhowie - true, then again there is no String.contains() method either ;-) Just the code looked like it contained workarounds for a broken (IMHO) version of `.indexOf()` in PHP's `strpos()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php requiring a double check.

Comment: @scunliffe , http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-array-contains/

Comment: @XCeptable - I revised my answer... if you just need to know that the first character is an "@", `if(value.indexOf('@') == 0)`

Comment: @XCeptable - ah... that contains() url is for Array objects, thus wouldn't apply to String values. The JavaScript `String.indexOf(String)` should cover all your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
var apos = value.indexOf('@');
if (apos >= 0) {
  // was found in string, somewhere
  if (apos == 0) {
    // was at start
  } else {
    // was elsewhere
  }
} else {
  // not in string
}
```

and

```
var apos = value.indexOf('@');
if (apos == 0) {
  // was at start
} else if (apos > 0) {
  // was elsewhere
} else {
  // not in string
}
```

Comment: though I did it by myself but its exactly same as yours answer(I added into edit). Perhaps your answer help me to gain confidence that my solution is not a work around only. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
if (apos !== 0) { /* error; */ }
```

The "apos" value will be the numeric value zero when your input is (as I understand it) valid, and either -1 or greater than 0 when invalid.

This seems like a strange thing to make a user of your site do, but whatever.  (If it's not there at all, and it **must** be there to be valid, why can't you just add the "@" for the user?)

Comment: @Pointy, will this condition then check both @ is at 1st place in the input & it is present in input too ??

Comment: @XCeptable: Yes.  `apos` will be -1 if the character is not present, or greater than 0 if the character is present, but not as the first character.  The return value of 0 means "the character is in the string, and it appears at the very beginning."

Comment: This doesn't check that it doesn't appear later.

Comment: Yes it does - "apos" would be a positive number if the "@" appeared somewhere in the string after the first character.  As far as I can tell, the whole point is to ensure that the input string starts with an "@" character. Now, given the strange wording of the question, I could of course be wrong.

Comment: @Pointy, actually I want to ensure as SLaks said, either it is at 1st or it is not in the string at all. This is not checking anything at all. I have had made one function that is working what I want, I put in in EDIT

Comment: Oh - then you'd want to check to see if it's -1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check to make sure that apos is greater than -1. Javascript's indexOf() will return the current index of the character you're looking for and -1 if it's not in the string.

**edit** Misread a bit. Also make sure that it's not equal to 0, so that it's not at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `if` condition, `apos` is a number, not a string.

You're trying to write

```
if (field.update.value.charAt(0) == '@' && field.update.value.indexOf('@', 1) < 0)
```

Comment: How number ? as it will contain what value is input by user

Comment: @XCeptable: Not after you write `apos=apos.indexOf('@')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function email_valid(field) 
    { 
      var fieldValue =field.update.value;
      var apos = apos.indexOf('@');
            if (apos > 0 || apos < 0)//could also use apos !== 0
              { alert('plz enter valid input');
                return false;
              }
            else 
            { return true; }
    }
```

`apos` is the value returned by [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), it will be -1 if there is no `@` in the user input. It will be 0 if it is the first character. It will be greater than 0 if the user input contains an `@` . JavaScript has no `contains` method on a String.

Comment: before posting this question I tried this was i.e.  (apos > 0 || apos < 0) but it did not work. !== 0 as mentioned by Pointy also do not work. I added code in EDIT that work fine for to check both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function email_valid(field) {
    //var apos=field.update.value;
    var apos = field;
    //apos=apos.indexOf('@');
    apos = apos.indexOf('@');
    if( (apos < 0) ) {
        //alert('plz enter valid input');
        alert('false');
    } else {
        alert('true');
    }
}
email_valid('blah');
```

Checks for `@` anywhere. Or, if you want to check for `@` just at the beginning, change `if( (apos < 0) ) {` to `if( (apos == 0) ) {`. Or, if you want to make sure it's not at the beginning, then `if( (apos > 0) ) {`.

Answer (score 0):

apos will be -1 if the string was not found. So your code should be as follows:

```
function email_valid(field) 
{ 
  var apos=field.value;
      apos=apos.indexOf('@');
        if (apos<=0) // handles '@' at the beginning and not in string at all.
        {
            alert('plz enter valid input');
            return false;
        }
        else 
        { return true; }
}
```

I also changed your initial assignment to remove the `.update` portion as that would cause it to fail when `field` is a reference to an input.

Comment: 2sholsinger, it is not checking anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Learn about Regular expressions if you haven't already. Then lookup Javascript's [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). There is no need to find wether the input starts with an "@" as if it **contains** an "@" that will also return true if the "@" is at the start of the string.

Also, for free, `return true` and `return false` are generally bad style. Just return the thing you passed to `if` (that evaluates to a boolean).

All in all:

```
function validate_input(str) {
    return str.match(/@/);
}
```

I reccomend passing the function a string (`field.value` or some-such) rather than the field itself as it makes it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** revised answer based on comments. code below will only return true if the value contains an "@" symbol at the first character.

If this is a JavaScript question, then this should be fine.

```
function email_valid(field){ 
  var apos=field.update.value;
  if(apos.indexOf('@') != 0){
    alert('plz enter valid input');
    return false;
  } else {
    //field contains an '@' at the first position (index zero)
    return true;
  }
}
```

That said, your parameter "field" if it actually refers to an input field element, should only require this code to get the value (e.g. I'm not sure where the ".update" bit comes into play)

```
var apos = field.value;
```

I would also rename this function if it isn't doing "email validation" to something a little more appropriately named.